# Include inside include in sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Basically I have a model called UserLadder that includes another model called User:

```
  try {
    const leaderboard = await UserLadder.findAll({
      where: {
        weeklyLadderId: req.params.id,
      },
      limit: req.params.playersNumber,
      attributes: ['userPoints'],
      include: [{ model: User, attributes: ['displayName', 'profilePicture'] }],
      order: [['userPoints', 'DESC']],
    });

    res.json(leaderboard);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error.');
  }
```

result:

```
[
    {
        "userPoints": 132.5,
        "user": {
            "displayName": "Ervin Howell",
            "profilePicture": "https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180926/igw/kisspng-league-of-legends-esports-logo-font-game-v-v-pls173-5bab06e810b838.0162687215379350800685.jpg"
        }
    },
    {
        "userPoints": 0,
        "user": {
            "displayName": "Leanne Graham",
            "profilePicture": "https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180926/igw/kisspng-league-of-legends-esports-logo-font-game-v-v-pls173-5bab06e810b838.0162687215379350800685.jpg"
        }
    }
]
```

but this user model have a relation with another model called RiotAccount and I was trying to figure out how to get the data of this third model to come with the user because I need it in the json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add "inner" include for the `User` model as below:

```
const leaderboard = await UserLadder.findAll({
  where: {
    weeklyLadderId: req.params.id,
  },
  limit: req.params.playersNumber,
  attributes: ['userPoints'],
  include: [{
    model: User,
    include: [{
      model: RiotAccount, attributes: [...]
    }]
    attributes: ['displayName', 'profilePicture'] 
  }],
  order: [['userPoints', 'DESC']],
});
```

Comment: how do you get the model: User to work? it doesn't work for me at all, I have to use the string names include: ['riotAccount']